# Pygame (Python) Scale Transform Slow

Tags: python, pygame, scaling, frame-rate

I'm writing a simple program in python which takes in data over the serial port and updates the screen.

Because I want this program to look the same on whatever computer it runs on, and it needs to be fullscreen, I had the idea that I wanted to draw everything in a small *640, 480* window, and then scale it to a fullscreen window every time I update the frame.

This allows me to keep all the offsets the same for text, etc. It also turns out this is really slow.

Here's about what the important part of the code looks like:

```
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080),pygame.FULLSCREEN)    
screenPrescaled=pygame.Surface((640,480))

clock=pygame.time.Clock()


while iterations<400:
#Blit all the stuff to the prescaled surface here
    screenPostscaled=pygame.transform.scale(screenPrescaled,(1920, 1080))
    window.blit(screenPostscaled,(0,0))
    pygame.display.flip() 
    iterations+=1
    clock.tick(40)
```

This runs a WHOLE lot slower than `40fps`.

Everything on the screen is either text or lines, there are no images loaded.
I suspect I'm doing something stupid.

I know I can update *"dirty rectangles"* only, but I wonder if I'm missing something more fundamental.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Scaling will be slow, so you don't want it every loop. Also, you could define offsets in percent of screen, like in OpenGl. And SVG graphics will scale no matter the resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save one blit by using window as [destination surface](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale):

```
pygame.transform.scale(screenPrescaled, (1920, 1080), window)
```

If it continues being too slow, you should use update rectangles, you can scale them using the same factor as you scale the image 1920/640 and 1080/480.

Comment: Thanks!  Removing that blit and using a transform destination really sped things up.  I timed the code at 40fps, which is great.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing is instead of using

```
pygame.display.flip()
```

is to use

```
pygame.display.update()
```

It's not that big of a difference but it worked pretty well for me on my game, especially when it uses a lot of pictures.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating a huge screen by `display.flip()`. In SDL (and that's behind pygame) that is not a good idea (try removing everything put the flip, and see how fast that runs, it shouldn't by to much faster).

I have no way to measure, but I would guess the reason your code takes a long time is a problem with the `.flip()`.

Since you are only working with data in 640x480, why are you scaling it up to such a huge dimension? Try setting your screen to 640x480, and take a look at how fast it will be then. It should run four or five times faster, I would think.

Comment: Thanks!  The idea is to have surface with known dimensions so I can place text, etc, where I want it.  Then, I scale it to the size of a full screen (which will be different for different machines).  Everything scales in proportion.  And you're right, it does run a lot faster at 640x480, but ultimately it can't be that small.

Comment: @Narrat1ve Might be you are lost there with SDL/pygame. I know of no way to make such big blit/updates faster. But than I never tried Overlay (for videos), OpenGL for pygame or other acceleration methods. You might want to take a look at them maybe.